# Trying to find the meaning of this tattoo

Tags: translation

my friend got it years ago and is  supposed to be his initials in chinese.. can you tell me if this is correct

[image]

Comment: "手" is actually written terribly... the hook at the bottom shouldn't be that long....

Answer (score 8):

女 (Nǚ) means:
(noun) female; woman; girl; daughter; frail

手 (Shǒu) means:
(noun) hand; clutch
(verb) hold; have in one's hand
(adjective) handy

女手: female's hand; female's writing

Comment: ABC also says: 女手 N. (sport) women's handball team